# How to adapt the old OpenGL ES 1 setup to iPhone 6 Plus?

Tags: ios, iphone, opengl-es, scale, framebuffer

If I'm not the last man on earth using the very 1st version of OpenGL ES: has anyone dealt with adapting the `resizeFromLayer` function to the new **3x** scaling on iPhone 6 Plus?

The code below works perfectly for all previous iPhones:

```
- (BOOL)resizeFromLayer:(CAEAGLLayer *)layer {
glGenFramebuffersOES(1, &viewFramebuffer);
glGenRenderbuffersOES(1, &viewRenderbuffer);

glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, viewFramebuffer);
glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, viewRenderbuffer);
[context renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES fromDrawable:layer];
glFramebufferRenderbufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, viewRenderbuffer);

glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH_OES, &backingWidth);
glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT_OES, &backingHeight);

glGenRenderbuffersOES(1, &depthRenderbuffer);
glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, depthRenderbuffer);
glRenderbufferStorageOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16_OES, backingWidth, backingHeight);
glFramebufferRenderbufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, depthRenderbuffer);

const GLfloat zNear = 0.1f, zFar = 8100.0f, fieldOfView = 60.0;
CGRect rect = layer.bounds;
GLfloat size;

glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
size = zNear * tanf(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(fieldOfView) / 2.0);

glFrustumf(-size, size, -size / (rect.size.width / rect.size.height), size / (rect.size.width / rect.size.height), zNear, zFar);

glRotatef(-90.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

if (glCheckFramebufferStatusOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE_OES)
{
    NSLog(@"Failed to make complete framebuffer object %x", glCheckFramebufferStatusOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES));
    return NO;
}

return YES;
```

}

Although I've updated the launch images for new phones (so the app detects 414x736 points), it still seems to act like it's working in 'zoomed mode' (for older apps).

Anyone sees a solution? I'd really appreciate your help.

Comment: Did you set an appropriate contentsScale on the layer? Should be 3.0 in your case I believe. Anyway what you posted works on all the versions of the openGL ES for iOS (except the matrix parts which really have nothing to do at all). All you need to get is an appropriate size of the buffer fromDrawable so you should check your backing width and height.

Comment: Yep, setting the `self.layer.contentsScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;` did the thing. Thanks a lot for a quick response!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the question is a bit off the issue topic we managed to find the solution. The problem is in getting the render buffer from the `UIView` layer which was returning a 1x scaled buffer meaning a resolution was too low. This issue is not bound to any version of the openGL ES on the iOS and can be produced on all versions.

You use a method `renderbufferStorage:fromDrawable:` which generates a render buffer storage from the layer. The layer itself needs to have its `contentScale` set to the screen scale to achieve an appropriate resolution using `self.layer.contentsScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;` as already mentioned in the comment.

Note that all other code is irrelevant in this matter.